EXCECUTE IMMEDIATE of dynamic query not generating results in DBeaver
I'm a beginner in SQL.
I'm using DBeaver v 24.1.3 on a mac to access an oracle database.
I'm using code to generate a dynamic query that calculates the percent of non-null rows for all columns in a table. The query creates a table with the column name and the percent non-null values. I'd like to generate the query results and save to file. I'll be doing this for multiple tables.
I can use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query); to print the query.
I'm then using
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query; to run the query. I'm doing this within a BEGIN / END; structure.
The code runs but no output table is generated.
If I copy and past the printed query in the SQL editor and run I do get the output table.
How can I generate the output table with a dynamic query?
Thanks very much in advance.
Full code below.
DECLARE
    column_name VARCHAR2(255);
    sql_query VARCHAR2(32767) := 'WITH column_non_nulls AS (';
    dynamic_select VARCHAR2(1000);
    total_count NUMBER;
    first_column BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
    -- Get the total number of rows in the table
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_count FROM GENERIC.TABLENAME;

    -- Loop through each column in the table and dynamically construct the query
    FOR col IN (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM all_tab_columns
        WHERE table_name = 'TABLENAME'
        AND owner = 'GENERIC'
    )
    LOOP
        column_name := col.column_name;

        -- Construct the dynamic SELECT part for each column
        dynamic_select := 'SELECT ''' || column_name || ''' AS column_name, ' ||
                          'ROUND(100 * COUNT(' || column_name || ') / ' || total_count || ', 2) AS percent_non_null ' ||
                          'FROM GMD.STUDIES WHERE ' || column_name || ' IS NOT NULL';

        -- Append the dynamic SELECT part to the SQL query
        IF first_column THEN
            sql_query := sql_query || dynamic_select;
            first_column := FALSE;
        ELSE
            sql_query := sql_query || ' UNION ALL ' || dynamic_select;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Close the CTE and the main SELECT query
    sql_query := sql_query || ') SELECT * FROM column_non_nulls ORDER BY percent_non_null DESC';

    -- Print the dynamically constructed SQL query for debugging purposes
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_query);

    -- Execute the dynamically generated SQL query
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query;

END;



A select query has to send its rows somewhere - that execute immediate isn't giving it anywhere for the rows to go to. You would need to either bulk collect them into a pl/sql collection and loop through it, or open a ref cursor and fetch through it. Either way, you'll need to loop through the rows and print each individually. That's not how we normally program, by the way - we would normally just grab the result desired and work with it rather than trying to display rows.

The query is parsed, but not executed; that part of your question is a duplicate this question really. To handle it here, do what PaulW said, or pass a ref cursor back to the caller (as a bind variable, if DBeaver allows that), or use the file/table approach...

thanks very much! What I'm really trying to do is save the data to a table that I can then export. I don't have permissions to create tables on the DB that I'm working with but when I run a query in DBeaver I get the results in table form that I can export.

The performance of this query would be terrible. Instead of UNION ALL select and count all columns and use PIVOT

It seems you have two unrelated questions: (1) how to report the percentage of non-null values for each column in a table, and (2) how to output the results of dynamic SQL in dBeaver. For (1), you could let Oracle do the work by gathering statistics and then query user_tab_col_statistics. For (2) I don't know dBeaver, but does it have a tool for opening cursors?
